# How do I kill players who don't fly throught hoops using elytra?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an elytra parkour, you must fly through hoops. I want to know how do I kill the player if they do not fly through the hoops. Specifically how you can focus that player, because knowing if the player did not go through is simple. But I do not know how I then focus that player instead of a random other player.

Comment: You say "knowing if the player did not go through is simple." Can you explain how you might accomplish that?

Comment: You can put command blocks so when u start a block disappears, so water can flow in a line. But the line is filled with blocks so the water is blocked. and for every hoop you fly through a block in that line of water disappears so the water can flow further. If you fly through all the hoops the water isn’t blocked and can reach the end and you can detect if the water is at the end. So a command block says ‘you finished’ or something.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a great Minecraft command guy, but for your problem,you can put barrier blocks around the hoops to make a wall with only the hoop as the way through, then the players who do not fly through the hoop will either die from impact or fall damage. If you want to be 100% let them die, you can put lava on the ground or cobwebs that leads to the void.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Cobwebs are brutal! You could just constantly kill every player in a cobweb block, though. :)

Comment: Yeah I though if that too, but it will ruin the map and lag it so I got rid of that idea